# ¿Como hago para que me aparezcan los textos ocultos una vez se recargue la página?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

El id del div y de los botones se genera en función de id del usuario, para que afecte exclusivamente a estos.

Php:

```
$resultados.= 
            '<i class="icon fa fa-plus fa-fw abrir" id="abrir_'.$row->userid.'" aria-hidden="true" hidden onclick="abrirResultado('.$row->userid.')" ></i>';
            $resultados.= 
            '<i class="icon fa fa-minus fa-fw cerrar" id="cerrar_'.$row->userid.'" aria-hidden="true"  onclick="cerrarResultado('.$row->userid.')" ></i>';

            $resultados .='<div class="columna_entera_resultados" id="columna_entera_resultados_'.$row->userid.'">';
```

JS:

```
function cerrarResultado(user){

    $('#abrir_'+user).removeAttr('hidden','');
    $('#cerrar_'+user).attr('hidden','');
    
    $('#columna_entera_resultados_'+user).hide();  
    
}

function abrirResultado(user){

    $('#abrir_'+user).attr('hidden','');
    $('#cerrar_'+user).removeAttr('hidden',''); 

    $('#columna_entera_resultados_'+user).show();             
        
}
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que si oculto el div siga apareciendo oculto una vez que recargue la página.

He intentado utilizar el

localStorage.setItem('show', 'true');
pero no consigo que se quede guardado.

Comment: Pero aparte de `localStorage.setItem` también has intentado leerlo luego? Porque si no das detalles, no podemos ayudarte. Cómo hacerlo es fácil, o en PHP gestionas también el hidden (nada te impide en php añadirle style: display: none;), o lo almacenas en el storage del navegador... Pero en cualquier caso, si tienes un problema específico debes dar datos del mismo! No puedo ayudarte si no veo lo que hacías que no te funcionaba.